# Knowing what CRS data is in?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile

In this case I'm working with [county lines](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html) from TIGER, but in general, I'm trying to sort out how to know what CRS my data is in.

I thought this would be in the shapefile's `.prj` but all I see there is:

```
EOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

Is there a reliable way to discern the CRS of any one shapefile?

Answer (score 4):

That is NAD83 as your Datum; so you shouldn't have any additional projection to worry about.

Sorry, I should have pointed that out. Your GEOGCS tells you that you are using the GCS (Lat/Long) based Coordinate Systems; then your DATUM being D_North_American_1983 points you to the NAD83.